# PostgreSQL - Syntax error at or near

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax-error

There are a lot of questions like this, but I couldn't find one that solved my problem-

Can someone tell me if my syntax is wrong? I'm trying to insert data into a sql table.

```
INSERT INTO awards values ('Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences’,'2007',’Best Picture','Oscar’);
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "2007"
LINE 1: ...s ('Academy of Motion Picture Arts and Sciences’,'2007',’Bes...
```

Comment: Wrong quote characters. Need simple apostrophe `'`..

Comment: `INSERT` without target column list is only a good idea for special cases. Typically, it is not since it is error-prone (in addition to your syntax error with the singele-quote).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you paste this from somewhere? Check and replace your quote character, you're using an invalid character (e.g. `’` instead of `'`) for quoting.